# An IEEE (or ISO/IEC/IEEE) standard which describes documentation requirements for a Software Development Plan

Tags: project-planning

Within IEEE Std. 12207-2008 is a description of the Software Development Life Cycle. Important for my purposes are the standards that derive from this regarding documentation. **What I'm looking for is an IEEE (or ISO/IEC/IEEE) standard which describes documentation requirements for a Software Development Plan (SDP)**.

I'm not sure if one exists. The best I can find is ISO/IEC/IEEE 15289-2015 which describes the numerous document types in section 10 (including an SDP) and IEEE 24748-5 for software development planning, which is in draft form.

I'm coming at this from a viewpoint of MIL-STD-498 which has a clearly defined SDP ([DI-IPSC-81427](http://www.letu.edu/people/jaytevis/Software-Engineering/MIL-STD-498/SDP-DID.pdf)) and looking for an IEEE 12207 derived alternative. **If one does not exist, does IEEE 12207 specify how to create documentation in cases where that standard (or related) do not specify?**

*If this is not on topic for this stack exchange, please let me know.*

Comment: You probably will not find one.  IEEE 12207 defers to the Contractor to decide what, if anything, it believes should go into each deliverable document.  MIL-STD-498 was written in the blood of program managers whose projects crashed and burned because they didn't do the work needed to deliver the documentation demanded in the associated DIDs.  (Note that MIL-STD-498 was a follow-on to DOD-STD-2167A, which derived from MIL-STD-1679 and from the 480/483/490 series.)

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm I feared as much. Given that that is the case, is there a standard procedure for how to define a document -- I don't see anywhere in 12207 that defines this. Might one simply use the MIL-STD-498 SDP DID for this specific document?

Comment: I'd rather get flogged than attempt to use a government standard for writing documentation again.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm pretty sure those governments have a cellar full of whips for that purpose.

Comment: @zephyr Yes, you are free to use the -498 SDP DID.  Or you can write your own, if you want to tailor things in or out.  You probably want to think hard about tailoring things out: most of those things got in the SDP DID in the first place because projects crashed and burned for not thinking about them in time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, while I sympathize with your distaste, I invite you to observe that the things in the SDP DID are, in general, things that will kill a project if they are NOT addressed during the planning phase of the project.  For example, the SDP DID asks about test equipment, facilities, and personnel.  Think about what happens to your project if you get to testing time and you don't have critical pieces of test equipment on hand.